# Applying multiple AffineTransformations in Batik

Tags: svg, zooming, affinetransform, batik, inverse

I am trying to scale and translate an SVG image in Batik.
To do the zooming I use

```
AffineTransform at= new AffineTransform();
at.scale(sx, sy);
at.translate(tx, ty);
canvas.setRenderingTransform(at, true);
```

That works quite fine (after I found out, that the `sx`, `sy`, `tx` and `ty` values must be **screen coordinates**, not **SVG coordinates**.

But I want to allow multiple scaling operations.
The problem is: I do not manage to "add" another transformation to the existing one.

I tried it by first reverting the old transformation and then appying the new one. But that gets me to another problem: The reversion doesn't work! It leads to an image that is smaller than the original one (thus zooming out).

I experimented a bit and tried to apply a transformation, then apply the inverse and then apply the original one again:

```
final AffineTransform at= new AffineTransform();
at.scale(zoom.sx, zoom.sy);
at.translate(zoom.tx, zoom.ty);
canvas.setRenderingTransform(at, true);
...
final AffineTransform reverseAt = at.createInverse();
canvas.setRenderingTransform(reverseAt, true);
...
final AffineTransform reverseBackAt= reverseAt.createInverse();
canvas.setRenderingTransform(reverseBackAt, true);
```

The first transformation is correct. The second one leads to rubbish, but appying the original one (or the inverse of the inverse) again, leads to the correct result.

So actually, there are two questions:

- What is the best way, to apply multiple zooming operations?
- Why is the result of the inverse transformation not what I expected?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, use [AffineTransform.concatenate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#concatenate-java.awt.geom.AffineTransform-):

```
AffineTransform firstTransform = new AffineTransform();
at.scale(sx, sy);
at.translate(tx, ty);

// Example: double all sizes
AffineTransform secondTransform = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(2, 2)

secondTransform.concatenate(firstTransform);
canvas.setRenderingTransform(secondTransform, true);
```